# Necessity of an 'empty' else statement in Python

Tags: python

I have now seen the following multiple times in some python tutorials.

```
if True:
    do something
else:
    pass
```

To me the else statement seems pretty unnecessary. Is this just to make the code more clear? Or is there some safety reason why this needs to be done? Thanks.

Comment: there is no reason to use it

Comment: Could you reference one of these tutorials that does this? That would help with context.

Comment: I was wondering who was teaching this non-pattern. No, there is absolutely no reason to use that.

Comment: What about equivalent of

Comment: This could be just to help those new to programming to get familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reason for an `else` to be there if you are not using it. It just may be the person's code style preference, but this is an unusual style choice that wastes space.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of much debate.

Some say it may be useful in certain circumstances:

- as a stub, where you are intending to add a future exception.
- in certain circumstances, where it may improve the readability of your code.

Some say never.

However, I would say an empty else statement is usually unnecessary, save where the above circumstances apply.